# How do you add / remove items to the very top menu item in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, 2013

The menu that I'm referring to is this one (the blue bar):

[image]

I've seen some deployments where people have custom items up here (for example, Outlook, linking to the organizations web Outlook client).

How can I go about doing this as I would love to be able to create a link to our web based Human Resources system from here, or, if this isn't possible, then just a link to our web Outlook client would be nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check these articles. You will get it here what you are looking for:

[Add/Remove links from SharePoint 2013 Suite Bar (SkyDrive, Sites, NewsFeed)](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/)

[Customizing SharePoint 2013 Suite Bar](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/findnavish/archive/2013/02/07/sharepoint-2013-customizing-suite-bar.aspx)

[Mastering SharePoint 2013 Suite Bar](http://spchris.com/2013/04/mastering-the-sharepoint-2013-suite-bar/)

You can also try a small jQuery code snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var suiteBar = $("#suiteBar").find(".ms-core-brandingText");
suite.html("<a href="www.stackexchange.com"> Your Outlook Link Name </a>");   
</script>
```

Hope this helps.